# Proguard move all obfuscated class to one package

Tags: java, android, proguard

By now I can keep some classes and methods etc via proguard, now that obfuscation works perfectly here is my question, I've noticed proguard happens to repackage some classes like this `com.a.a`, `com.a.b`, is there a way to avoid leaving hints like `com.x.x` and put all of the obfuscated classes in one package like `a.a.**`? (real life example of a hint I've seen looks like `org.apache.a.x`, anyone decompiling my code will immediately skip that particular package because it reeks of library jar, i want to merge obfuscated library and obfuscated original code into one package). i tried this config but it didn't work.

```
        -allowaccessmodification
        -mergeinterfacesaggressively
        -useuniqueclassmembernames
        -keeppackagenames doNotKeepAThing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-repackageclasses
```

this didn't put obscufated classes on a particular package, but this is what I intended to do, the remaining packages you see there are the ones I've explicitly kept, also if you have resources (files) embedded in a package those would still be retained in it original package structure but their obscufated .class files will be moved to the root

Update 1

yes you can, code below will move obfuscated classes from root to package `a.a`

```
-repackageclasses a/a
```

[image]